# How to get the right meaning of particles

Tags: meaning, particles

Since Japanese is a left branching language, do you have trouble getting the right meaning of words or particles like the particle で in the next sentence (which can indicate location of action and means of action too)

> ところで、みなさんは　“ほぼほぼ”という言葉を　聞いたことがありますか？ 実は、この言葉は、辞書**で**有名な三省堂が主催した今年の新語大賞に選ばれました。

I assume that seeing it at first, you wouldn't know if it's talking about "being in/at the dictionary" or "because of the dictionary" (in this case "because it makes dictionaries/famous for its dictionaries")

Comment: I wonder if it is 'in the genre of the dictionary'. 三省堂 is a famous publishing company of dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt there is nothing confusing in this sentence. ～**で**有名な is a basic set phrase that directly corresponds to "being famous **for** ～," and you should be able to interpret 辞書で有名な三省堂 as "Sanseido, which is famous for dictionaries" instantly. Lots of examples [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=famous%20for&ref=sa).

If 辞書で does not go well with something right after it, it may be modifying something distant. For example:

> 辞書で聞いた単語を調べた。

would almost certainly mean "I looked up in a dictionary the word that I heard", not "I looked up the word that I heard in the dictionary". 辞書で modifies not 聞いた but 調べた, and I can say that because 辞書で聞いた doesn't make sense.

In this case, 辞書で主催する and 辞書で選ばれる do not make much sense to me anyway, while 辞書で有名 is instantly understandable.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's all about set phrases then. Also those distant modifiers are kinda tricky sometimes

Comment: Yeah distant modifiers are always difficult because multiple interpretations are technically possible...

Comment: @Jon  English has similar issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence