# Undertstanding ８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵などが有名な芸術家で

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-が, relative-clauses, reading-comprehension

> ８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵などが有名な**芸術家**で、世界でも人気があります。
>   88 year old 草間彌生さん ??? and is popular even in (the rest of) the world.

I'm having problems parsing the first clause.

> 草間彌生さんは有名な芸術家で
>   草間彌生 is a famous artist -- (makes sense)
>   水玉の絵などが有名な芸術家で
>   things like the water drop picture are famous artists -- (does not make sense)

It sounds to me like it's saying that the picture is an artist.
If 芸術家 was replaced by a word for art work (maybe 芸術品?) rather than artist then I'd be happy. As it stands I can't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[～**で**有名だ is "to be famous *for* ～"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/how-to-get-the-right-meaning-of-particles/42345#42345). You can always say 水玉の絵などで有名な芸術家.

> 草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**で**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。

However, this sentence:

> 草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**が**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。

...also makes perfect sense, and has almost the same meaning. In this case, 水玉の絵などが有名な modifies 芸術家 as a relative clause. Its "base" sentence would be この芸術家は水玉の絵が有名だ, which is an example of so-called "double subject" sentences like ゾウは鼻が長い.

In other words, 水玉の絵などが有名な芸術家 is structurally similar to 鼻が長いゾウ, ニンジンが好きなウサギ, 心が美しい人, etc.

**EDIT:** Strictly speaking, 水玉の絵が有名な芸術家 is an artist whose art is famous; the artist himself doesn't necessarily have to be famous. For example, you can say 「彼は花の絵が有名な画家だが、彼自身の名前はあまり知られていない」.

Answer (score 1):

## English

I think the question is very good because I think even native speakers of Japanese don't exactly know the difference of subtle nuance between these two particles **が** and **で** and how to use them properly in an actural situation.

Note: If there is a difference in nuance between Japanese and English in the following sentences (1) - (4), Japanese takes precedence.

> （１）８８歳{さい}の草間{くさま}彌生{やよい}さんは水玉{みずたま}の絵{え}など**が**有名{ゆうめい}な芸術{げいじゅつ}家{か}で、世界{せかい}でも人気{にんき}があります。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist whose polka dot paintings and the like are famous, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world.*
>
> （２）８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**で**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。
> *Ms.Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist famous for polka dot paintings and the like, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world.*

Both (1) and (2) are correct grammatically and also as Japanese.
But you should explain Ms. Kusama by the sentence with (2) instead of (1) because (1) is **rude** to her.

I said (1) is correct grammatically and also as Japanese, but you should write it correctly in the actual situation too, because she is a famous artist instead of unknown person.

Let me explain the reason by simpifying (1) and (2) into (3) and (4).

> （３）草間｛くさま｝彌生｛やよい｝さんは水玉｛みずたま｝の絵｛え｝**が**有名｛ゆうめい｝な芸術｛げいじゅつ｝家｛か｝です。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama is an artist whose polka dot paintings are famous*.
>
> （４）草間彌生さんは水玉の絵**で**有名な芸術家です。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama is an artist famous for polka dot paintings*.

In Japanese there is a big difference between (3) and (4), though I don't know whether it is well described in my poor attempt of my English translations.
In (3), the famous one is "paintings of polka dots", while in (4), the famous one is "Ms. Kusama" herself.

Ms. Kusama is a famous painter and/or artist in reality.

The sentence with (4) briefly shows that she is a famous artist, while (3) doesn't describe whether she is famous or not.
As for (3), it is well written in the following explanation in the naroto's answer.

> **EDIT**: Strictly speaking, 水玉の絵が有名な芸術家 is an artist whose art is famous; the artist himself doesn't necessarily have to be famous. For example, you can say 「**彼は花の絵が有名な画家だが、彼自身の名前はあまり知られていない**」.

English translation is my attempt.

> **彼｛かれ｝は花｛はな｝の絵｛え｝が有名｛ゆうめい｝な画家｛がか｝だが、彼｛かれ｝自身｛じしん｝の名前｛なまえ｝はあまり知｛し｝られていない**。
> *He is a painter whose paintings of flowers are famous, but his own name is not well known*.

How do you think Ms. Kazama feels if she is introduced by the words with the nuance like what is used for the not well-known painter?

If you don't understand the nuance of the particles of **が** and **で** in those above examples, I think that most Japanese people can be satisfied with the following explantion using examples (5) and (6).

> （５）タイガーウッズは数々｛かずかず｝の記録｛きろく｝**が**有名｛ゆうめい｝なゴルファーです。
> *Tiger Woods is a golfer whose record-breaking performance is famous*.
>
> （６）タイガーウッズは数々の記録**で**有名なゴルファーです。
> *Tiger Woods is a golfer famous for his record-breaking performance*.

When most Japanese people read (5), they will feel somewhat strange for a moment. And they are not satisfied with it as an introduction of Tiger Woods.  Tiger Woods has a lot of elements other than the "record-breaking performance" that made him famous.
However, there is no room to introduce other elements in (5), which focuses only on the theme that "his record-breaking performance is famous". Speaking of golfers with "excellent performance", you can mention players like A, B and C, but the topic will branches off from Tiger Woods himself.

On the other hand, if you read (6), everyone will be satisfied.
This sentence focuses on the theme that Tiger is famous. If you want to spice up the story, you can add various topics based on Tiger Woods.

Finally, (2) is a sentence that both "Ms. Kusama" and "her works" can be correctly introduced to be famous, while if you use (1) to introduce her, it becomes rude to her.

## 日本語

> （１）８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**が**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist whose polka dot paintings and the like are famous, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world*.

一般に、この「が」は間違いなく添削されて（２）のようになります。

> （２）８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**で**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist famous for polka dot paintings and the like, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world*.

仮に、誰もが知っている「水玉の絵」が世界でも人気があるが、画家である８８歳の草間彌生さんは有名でないということを想定した文を書く必要がある場合でも、「てにをは」で微妙なニュアンスを伝えられるかもしれないというようなあやふやな選択をせず、次のようにきちんと書くのが普通で間違いも少ないと思います。

> （３）この水玉の絵**は**有名で、世界でも人気がありますが、その画家の草間彌生さんは余り知られておりません。因みに８８歳でなお現役です。

「水玉の絵など」の「など」は指すものが不明確ですので「有名」の対象になりませんので、（３）では書き表しません。また、草間彌生さんが有名でないので、この文章とともに参考になる水玉の絵を写真で掲載する必要があります。従って、写真なしの（３）も現実には存在しない文章です。

結論として、（１）ではなく（２）を使うと覚えてください。

---

## EDIT

> （１）８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**が**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist whose polka dot paintings and the like are famous, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world*.
>
> （２）８８歳の草間彌生さんは水玉の絵など**で**有名な芸術家で、世界でも人気があります。
> *Ms. Yayoi Kusama of 88 years old is a Japanese artist famous for polka dot paintings and the like, and is popular not only in Japan but also all over the world*.

（１）と（２）はともに文法的にも、日本語としても正しいです。
それでは、私が最初の回答で（１）ではなく（２）とするべきだとした理由を含めて説明します。

桜で有名な〇〇公園の最寄りの駅で尋ねられました。

> （３）「桜**で**有名なところはどこですか？」
> （４）「桜**が**有名なところはどこですか？」

（３）の答えは「〇〇公園です。」
（４）の答えは「（４-１）そこの角を曲がって坂を登ったところです/ところにあります。」あるいは、「（４-２）〇〇公園ですね。そこの角を曲がって坂を登ったところにあります。」

（３）は明らかに公園の名前を尋ねています。
（４）の場合、公園の名前よりも、その公園の所在を訪ねている雰囲気があります。質問者の意図が正確にわからない場合は（４-２）が親切な回答ですが、取りあえずは（４-１）でも良いでしょう。駅前で（４）として具体的に尋ねられているときに、「〇〇公園です。」だけでは間違いである可能性が高いと思います。きっと「いやいや公園の名前ではありません。どういったら良いか分からないのです。」あるいは「〇〇公園って言うのですね。ありがとうございます。それはこの坂の上ですか？」のような会話が続くでしょう。

（３）は公園が有名なのです。
（４）は桜が有名なのです。

（３）の場合は「桜」で有名ですが、「西郷さんの銅像」でも有名な場合ですと、（３）は、「桜でも有名なところはどこですか？」となり、「公園」を中心にいろいろな修飾語が考えられます。
（４）の場合は、「桜」が有名な中心ですので、「桜が有名なのは〇〇公園以外に△△公園もあります。」という具合に、文章の展開方向が（３）とは異なる可能性が大いにあります。

（３）と（４）の本質的な違いの内、（３）については、nartoさんが答えの中で次のように上手に説明しています。

> EDIT: Strictly speaking, 水玉の絵が有名な芸術家 is an artist whose art is famous; the artist himself doesn't necessarily have to be famous. For example, you can say 「彼は花の絵が有名な画家だが、彼自身の名前はあまり知られていない」.

ところで、最初の「草間彌生さんの水玉の絵」に戻りましょう。分かりやすくするために、有名人を登場させます。

> （５）タイガーウッズは数々の記録**が**有名なゴルファーです。
> （６）タイガーウッズは数々の記録**で**有名なゴルファーです。

（５）の文を読んだとき、多くの人が多分「？」、「何か変だな」と一瞬感じるのではないかと思います。そして、これではタイガーウッズを紹介する文としてはまずいなと感じるはずです。何故でしょうか。
（５）の表現では、タイガーよりも、「数々の記録が有名」という文言が表にでてきます。本当は、タイガーを世界的に有名にした理由は、「数々の記録」もさることながら、それ以外に沢山あるからです。しかし、（５）の表現では、「数々の記録が有名」と言い切っていますので、タイガーに関してそれ以外の事実や出来事などを追加する余地がないからです。何か追加したくてもう一度（５）を見ますと、「数々の記録で有名なゴルファー」というところに考えが行きます。タイガーに限らず世界的に有名なプレーヤーを考えると、何人かの名前を挙げることはできますし、日本でも松山英樹や石川遼の名前が浮かびます。しかし、それでは、タイガーを有名だと讃｛たた｝えたい話題からは逸｛そ｝れていってしまいます。

一方、（６）の文を見ると、タイガーを紹介する文としては問題ないと皆は感じるはずです。
それは、この文が「タイガーウッズそのものが有名である」と焦点を定めて、有名になった事例を紹介しているからです。この方法なら、いくらでも彼を讃える話題を追加できます。

「が」と「で」の違いだけで、（６）ではタイガーが主役、（５）ではタイガーでなく「数々の記録」が主役になってしまい、これほどまでニュアンスの違いを生じるのです。

さて、草間彌生さんの水玉の絵の記述に本当に戻ります。「が」を使った（１）は基本的に「水玉の絵」が有名だと述べております。確かに草間彌生さんの絵は大変有名です。お名前はタイガーウッズほと有名ではないのかも知れませんが、（２）ではなく（１）の文章を使った（公表する）原稿の場合、「草間さんのことはあまり知られていないが絵は有名である」との印象が残るので、編集上は推敲が入り「が」を「で」に修正するのが穏当です。（１）では、草間さんに失礼になる可能性があるからです。

本当に有名でない人や場所である場合、そして人や場所に興味がない場合は「〇〇が有名」で全く問題ありませんが、それ以外の場合は「〇〇で有名」の表現が穏当です。

narutoさんが挙げた以下の例はいずれもゴシック体の部分が有名なので、「フリーキックが有名なロベルト・カル‌​ロス」を除いて「が」で問題ありません。（５）に近いニュアンスを持つ「カルロス」の文では編集で修正が入りそうです。
「**糸桜**が有名な近衛家の屋敷は…」
「**アンズ**が有名なところってどこですか？」
「**常夏プール**が‌​有名なサマーランド」
「**紅葉**が有名なお寺で‌​…」
「フリーキックが有名なロベルト・カル‌​ロス」
「**ヨセミテの絵**が有名な画家の名前が‌​思い出せません」

Comment: BCCWJでちょっと検索するだけで「糸桜が有名な近衛家の屋敷は…」「アンズが有名なところってどこですか？」「常夏プールが有名なサマーランド」「紅葉が有名なお寺で…」「フリーキックが有名なロベルト・カルロス」「ヨセミテの絵が有名な画家の名前が思い出せません」などの例が沢山見つかりますけど、これらはすべて誤りですか？ 私には全く普通の文のように思えます。

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't down vote this, but it's way too difficult for me to understand with my current level of Japanese.

Comment: @user3856370: I'm sorry to write it only in Japanese. Give me a time. I'm going to write my answer in English. Besides for you, I myself thought I had to make it more clear the use of が and で to let you know how you should use these partcles correctly.

Comment: 貴方個人の前提知識がある有名人を使うから、逆に混乱しているのでは。仮想の木村さんがいたとして、「スポーツが有名な木村さん」「科学が有名な木村さん」は不思議な表現ですが、「ダンクシュートが有名な木村さん」「鳥類研究が有名な木村さん」は本人の知名度に関わらず、新聞記事に出てもおかしくない自然な表現に思えます。如何でしょう？　「で」には広く所属分野を指し示す働きがありますが、「が」にはそのような機能はありませんよね。

Comment: @naruto: 私も「スポーツが有名」は例が間違っていると思って書き直している最中です。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @naruto: 「白髪が有名な老人が突然訪ねて来た」はありですが、「白髪で有名な老人が突然訪ねて来た」はおかしい。それを言うなら「白髪で有名な〇〇さんが突然訪ねて来た」は問題なし。この辺りで書きたかったのですが、タイガーウッズで押し通しました。またよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ①そもそもOPは単にparsingでミスをしていただけで、「で」と「が」の違いなんて聞いていません。②違いを語るにしても、編集の度に意見が変わりすぎです。最初は「てにをはで微妙なニュアンスを伝えられるかもしれない（程度の差しかない）」はずだったのに、いつから「大きな違いでありNHKは重大で失礼なミスをした」という意見に変わったのですか。③「が」に貴方が考えるような裏の意味は普通ありません。これが「絵は有名な人」「顔は綺麗な人」「テストの成績はよい東大生」のように「は」が使ってあれば、裏の意味を読み取れて失礼にもなり得るでしょう。でも普通に「が」を使って「顔が綺麗な人」「プールが有名な遊園地」と言っただけで、文脈も無視して「性格はブスってことか！プール以外に何もないと言ってるのか！失礼だ！」とかいちいち怒る人とはまともに会話できません。元記事は明らかに草間氏を有名人として扱っており、悪しく解釈する余地はありません。

Comment: @mackygoo Thank you for translating. It seems like naruto-san doesn't agree with you, but I think I understand the point you are making. The difference would be very subtle in English and only really seen as rude if one was deliberately trying to take offense.

Comment: @naruto: いつも丁寧にお読みいただき示唆に富むコメントありがとうございます。つい早とちりで質問を勘違いしてしまいます。大いに反省。また、言い忘れていたことが気になり追加している内に、最初の意見からすっかりズレているように映っているようですが、これも反省。なお、助詞ひとつでニュアンスが変わることがありますが、受け取り方は人それぞれなのでしょうね。