# Odd position of adjective

Tags: adjectives, grammar

In one exercise I'm doing, it has the following sentence:

> *世界で一番木の古い建物は法隆寺です。*

In this case, the position of the adjective 古い looks odd to me. I normally find it appear before noun or noun phrase, so I think it should be:

> *世界で一番古い木の建物は法隆寺です。*

Is there a mistake with printing or something I should know about here?

Based on the content of that exercise, the sentence has the English translation as follows:

*The oldest wooden building in the world.*

Comment: On second thought, it might have a chance to be a valid sentence in some limited situation, so could you provide a context?

Comment: That's weird. The word 木の popped out of nothing (nor 法隆寺).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two phrases are not identical. The difference is as follows:

1. 世界で一番木の古い建物 = the building whose wood is oldest in the world
2. 世界で一番古い木の建物 = the oldest wooden building in the world

The latter simply refers to the oldest building made of wood, which is 法隆寺. The former refers to a building which uses very old tree. Strictly speaking, the building itself does not necessarily have to be old. Yes, if you have 10000-year-old trees, you can use them and start building a 世界で一番木の古い建物 today. (Well, this is a nit-picky discussion; practically speaking, they refer to almost the same thing...)

木の古い建物 is the same as 木が古い建物, which has a relative clause that modifies 建物. If you know how to parse 鼻の長いゾウ, 心が綺麗な人, 背の高い男 and so on, you can parse 木の古い建物 the same way. (See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53581/5010) if you are unsure.)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that 世界で一番木の古い建物 should not be translated as "the oldest wooden building in the world"?

Comment: @kandyman 世界で一番木の古い建物 is a bit puzzling, so I would see the context or ask the original writer for clarification. It may be "the oldest wooden building" or "the building made of the oldest wood".

Comment: @kandyman I added the context: Based on the content of that exercise, the sentence has the English translation as follows:
*The oldest building in the world.*

Comment: @petwho do you mean “the oldest wooden building”?

Comment: @kandyman edited man, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @petwho If you want to simply say "the oldest wooden building", it's way more natural to say 一番古い木の建物, as you pointed out. Your exercise is not wrong, but it's a little odd...

Comment: @naruto That's exactly what I think, there should be some revise for the source countent.

Comment: @naruto Is it similar to the concept of using の as noun modifier when done after another particle like, 7時からのパーティーに行きます (Wherein の enables 7 to modify from 7, the noun party rather than 行きます i.e. party from 7 (or party starting from 7))? or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the が to の conversion which happens in relative clauses and attributive clauses. The usual 木**が**古い gets converted to 木**の**古い because it is embedded in the clause and is modifying a noun. See below for a similar discussion on this topic:

- [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)

As for using 木が古い instead 古い木, this is not uncommon when describing some kind of attribute or a personality trait. The format is `NounがAdjective` where the adjective describes one particular attribute of the noun (but implies there are others).

Comment: Is 木 an noun here? I read it as tree at first but it should be translated as the adjective “wooden”, right?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that. In that case, disregard my answer. I'll delete it.

Comment: When 木 is translated as "wooden", isn't that just to produce more idiomatic English? In Japanese, it should still be a noun. In this case, the sentence literally talks about the building where the wood (used to build it) is the oldest in the world. So I think kandyman's answer that this is an issue with が/の conversion still stands.

Comment: I'm still not sure about this I do think 一番木の古い建物 can be translated as 'oldest wooden building' since the literal translation can be 'building with the oldest wood', using the attributive phrasing I reference in my answer.